# DJango rest framework createapiview

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Im using Django rest framework CreateAPIView to create some data and here is the view.

```
class CompanyCreateApiView(CreateAPIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'request ==', request
        for each in args:
            print 'args ==', each
        for each in kwargs:
            print 'keargs ==', each
        import json
        data=json.dumps({'status':'success'})
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

now I call this viewset using python request module and don't see post data being printed in *Args or **kwargs parameter

**

```
import requests
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create-company-profile/',data={'key':'value'})
print r.status_code
print r.text
```

**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't see any POST data in those; instead, you will see it in `request.data`. As described in the [django-rest-framework documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data):

> request.data returns the parsed content of the request body. This is similar to the standard request.POST and request.FILES attributes except that:
>
> - It includes all parsed content, including file and non-file inputs.
> - It supports parsing the content of HTTP methods other than POST, meaning that you can access the content of PUT and PATCH requests.
> - It supports REST framework's flexible request parsing, rather than just supporting form data. For example you can handle incoming JSON data in the same way that you handle incoming form data.

Answer (score 0):

You don't see any response because they are empty, it's like

```
for item in []:
   print item
```

it can't iterate over empty data, but in case you send a value in the url:

```
url(r'^/api/create-company-profile/(?P<name>\w+)/$', CompanyCreateApiView.as_view()),
```

kwargs will have the following value `{"name": comany_name}`

in order to retrieve the data send in the body of the request you use `request.data`, you may find also some example in the internet such as `request.DATA` or `request.QUERY_PARAMS`, but it's deprecated in the newer version of django and replaced by `request.data`